# ElasticSearch newbie - creating the first index

Tags: elasticsearch

Have a client that thinks this will be *awesome* to use to crawl volumes of 10MB log files.  I'd agree having read up on it, but seem stuck on creating my first index.  So far:

♦ Installed `ElasticSearch 1.2.1` on Windows 8, and `Curl 7.3.7` (HTTP for SSL, here: paehl.com/open_source/?CURL_7.37.0)
♦ Successful in a response from ES (status 200, hurrah, on localhost, 127.0.0.1 or my machine's IP all good with a 200 status)
♦ When I try to create an index, however, no love.  Been trying to follow steps from both the Joel Abrahamsson's ElasticSearch 101 (joelabrahamsson.com/elasticsearch-101/) and Park's "ES Cookbook".  Errors range, but most recently and shortest are on par with these:

```
C:\>curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/blog/user/dilbert' -d '{ "name" : "Dilbert Brown" }'
curl: (1) Protocol 'http not supported or disabled in libcurl
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: name
curl: (7) Failed to connect to  port 80: Connection refused
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Dilbert Brown
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 1
```

Earlier messages were far more wordy:

```
C:\>curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test1/test/1" -d' { "title" : "Godfather", "director" : "Coppola", "year" : 1972 }'
{"error":"MapperParsingException[failed to parse]; nested: ElasticsearchParseException[Failed to derive xcontent from (offset=0, length=1): [39]]; ","status":400}curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace in column 1
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: title
curl: (7) Failed to connect to  port 80: Connection refused
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Godfather,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: director
curl: (7) Failed to connect to  port 80: Connection refused
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Coppola,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: year
curl: (7) Failed to connect to  port 80: Connection refused
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 1972
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 1
```

It feels like I'm overlooking something basic, but as a newbie to ES, curl and JSON, I'm puzzled -- and at least from my seat, the brace/brackets appear balanced.

Suggestions?

Comment: Can you try `curl "http://google.com"`? It seems you may have some `libcurl` issues. Might be easier to try a [REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) instead of the command line.

Comment: +1 for REST Client, I think you're having quoting problems.

Comment: @PaulG I'm having trouble installing Elasticsearch on windows. If you can, could you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25748854/rails-4-elasticsearch-on-windows

Answer (score 3):

It's a problem with the `cmd` of Windows.
You can fix it by changing:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/blog/user/dilbert' -d '{ "name" : "Dilbert Brown" }'
```

to:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/blog/user/dilbert" -d "{ """name""" : """Dilbert Brown""" }"
```

Update: **(for windows 64 bit)**

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/blog/user/dilbert" -d "{ \"name\" : \"Dilbert Brown\" }"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems windows does not like the single quote thing around the url. I cannot test it for you but try it with double quotes around the url.

I got this info from the following blogpost:
http://bartwullems.blogspot.nl/2013/08/curl-1-protocol-not-supported-or.html

Answer (score 0):

Create a local file with the json request message as indicated in the elasticsearch tutorial, go to this directory and execute the curl command, referencing this file:

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/shakespeare --data-binary "@_01_specify_schema.json"
```

where _01_specify_schema.json is a file containig:

```
{
 "mappings" : {
  "_default_" : {
   "properties" : {
    "speaker" : {"type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
    "play_name" : {"type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
    "line_id" : { "type" : "integer" },
    "speech_number" : { "type" : "integer" }
 }}}}
```

Take care to add the "@" symbol before the name of the referenced file